# EXPRESS: express.urlencoded IS NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, backend

I don't know why  console.log(req.body) is not showing any output if anyone can explain why
when I fill the details and submit it then req.body should print details in terminal but it shows nothing
I am new to nodejs please also explain why actually it is not printing output

code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

//express related stuff
app.use('/static',express.static('static'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

//pug specific stuff 
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));

//endpoint

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    const con = "knowledge";
    const parans = {'title':'PUBG','content': con};
    res.status(200).render('index.pug',parans);
});
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const parans = {'message': 'your form has been submitted'};
    res.status(200).render('index.pug',parans);
})

//listen,port
app.listen(80,()=>{
    console.log("sucess on port 80");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>#{title}</title>
    style
        include ../static/style.css
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/joinus">JOIN_US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>HEADING</h1>
    <!--<h2>#{content}</h2>
    <p>this is plain HTML using PUG</p>-->
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/" id="contact">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="ENTER YOUR NAME">
            <input type="text" id="AGE" placeholder="ENTER YOUR AGE">
            <input type="text" id="GENDER" placeholder="ENTER YOUR GENDER">
            <button class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the coding you have set up for route `app.post('/', …)` to trigger here? No reason that should happen - your `form` element does not have an explicit `method` set, so the default form submission method `GET` will be used.

Answer (score 2):

`express.urlencoded()` can't parse those input-fields which lack `name` attribute.

To solve the problem, just add HTML name attributes to each input tag inside the `<form>`.

example:

```html
 <input name='name' type='text'>
 <input name='age' type='number'>
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -2):

first install npm install body-parser then Add these lines

```
Code:
 const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extnded: true }));
```

Comment: sending data from client or empty json .check correctly

Comment: let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('content-type','application/json');
fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(form_data)
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log("response..");
    return response.json();
}).then(function (user_json) {
    console.log(user_json);
});