# How to output results in a table from a pug file with a select dropdown to another pug file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, pug

So, i made one page that has a select dropdown with a bunch of book titles from a [json file](https://notepad.link/jsr32). When you choose a book and click submit it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BVMU.png) it should then render you to another page called /showBooks and it should output all the information of that book like [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZLC.png) I am able to render to a new page but no information shows up. Im having trouble getting the id value from the select drop-down and transferring it to showBooks.
This is my Main.js

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));
const inD = require("./input/books.json");

let books = inD.books;

app.get("/forms", function( req, res){
    res.render( 'Forms',{
        lib : inD.library,
        desc : inD.description,
        bks : books
        })
});
app.post("/showBook", function( req, res){
    let id = req.params.id;
    let title = req.params.title;
    let value = req.params.value;
    res.render( 'FormsBooks',{
        id : id,
        title : title,
        value : value
    });
    console.log(`yesitem:${id}`);

});
```

and this is my forms.pug

```
include Header.html
head
    title Books
    script(type='text/javascript').
        function checkIt(){
            const select = document.getElementById('name');
            alert(select.value);
        }
body
    h2  #{lib}

    p #{desc}

    h3 Select a book
    br
    div(class="col-sm-12")
            div.form-group(class="sel")
            form(action ="/showBook" method="POST")
                select(type='text', id='name')
                    for bk in bks
                        option(value = bk.id) #{bk.title}
                button.btn.btn-primary(onclick=`checkIt()`) Submit it
    br
    p by me
```

and my formsBooks.pug (showbooks)

```
include Header.html
head
    title Form Tester
body
    h2  Book Details for id:#{id}
    div.col-sm-6
        H1
        table.table
          tr
            th Item
            td #{id}
            th title
            td #{title}
            th author
            td #{value}
            th Year
            td #{id}
            th Editions
            td #{title}
            th Price
            td #{value}
                button(class='btn btn-primary' type='button' onClick=`location.href='/formsBooks/delete/'`) Delete

    button.btn.btn-primary(type="button", name="asdf" onclick="location.href='/Forms'" value='back') Back to form
```

So i made my button into an onClick and when i click 'submit' it alerts me the value.id of the book i have chosen. I just dont know how to make it so i can use that id to output the information of that book. I also tried adding a link to the onClick button but didnt seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix select tag's `name` attribute, change it to this:

```
select(type='text', name='id')
```

On the server, to read post data, use `req.body`, not `req.params`.

You need to setup body parser to process form:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extnded: true }));
```

`id` will be in `req.body.id` (it corresponds to the form's `name` attribute), so you can get the book by searching it within `books` array by `req.body.id`, instead of passing all the data within the form, and then pass the whole object to `formsBooks.pug`, for example:

```
const book = books.find(b=>b.id==req.body.id) || {err:'no such book'};

res.render( 'FormsBooks', {book});
```

Comment: okay, whats the difference between name='id' and id='name'? and im able to see the id popping up in the url so thats good! but i get an error saying 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') '

Comment: @xkellss you need to install and setup body parser (use `express.urlencoded` in this case), you can see it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871076/express-express-urlencoded-is-not-working) and it also explains `name` attribute

Comment: I installed and set up body-parser, but still seem to get the same error about id. Is my app.get("/showBook/", right? or should i be adding id to it?

Comment: @xkellss it should be `app.post("/showBook/`, not get..

Comment: okay, i was able to get it. Thank you so much!!